# Can Hibernate data access throw exceptions similar to Spring DeadlockLoserDataAccessException or other TransientDataAccessException?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, exception, runtimeexception

I'm currently working on a project that uses data access on different databases. Our main database is accessed through Hibernate (either via the `Criteria` framework, or HQL queries), but we also have accesses to other dbs using plain JDBC / SQL queries (via Spring-Jdbc).

For some of our JDBC calls, we had to deal with the possibility of the DAO layer throwing some flavours of the Spring runtime `TransientDataAccessException`, like `DeadlockLoserDataAccessException`, or `CannotAcquireLockException`.

**My question:** should we plan for similar exceptions thrown by the Hibernate DAOs? It's very difficult to write tests that would exhibit such exceptions, and I don't want to build support for these if they cannot be thrown. And if they can, which exceptions exactly? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions thrown from your Spring backed persistence implementation are not really rooted in Spring => they are *data access exceptions*.

Hence you *can* get similar exceptions from a pure Hibernate implementation e.g:

[LockAcquisitionException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/exception/LockAcquisitionException.html): indicating a problem acquiring lock on the database

Having said that, testing for these exceptions specifically would not be wise. Hence they are `RuntimeException`s. If you getting these exceptions from your Spring backed implementation, I would rather focus on *solving* the problem.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. There's no real point trying to catch exceptions which indicate a problem in the architecture. Better solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the hibernate Session api, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html you; specifically, createQuery and createCriteria.

createQuery, which takes an hql string, returns a Query object and throws a HibernateException.  createCriteria returns a Criteria object with no exceptions thrown. Calling .list() on a Criteria or Query object throws a HibernateException.

Most of the function calls, if they throw an exception, throw a HibernateException.  There are a few special cases like calling uniqueResult() on a Query object, which throws a NonUniqueResultException, in addition to a HibernateException.

Comment: Yes I knew about these, I was more asking about similar exception to the ones I list. I guess my question was more: what happens when Hibernate encounters a Deadlock or similar problem? Does it try to fix it by itself, does it throw a specific exception? I guess I'll browse the exceptions hierarchy below HibernateException. Thanks anyway for answering, I voted you up!